# Node shipping API using Shippo isn't working

Tags: html, node.js, http, api-design, shippo

I'm building an API and today I integrated my with a HTML form. However, it just says 'Cannot POST /newship'. What is wrong?
My server.js:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var http = require('http');
//Shippo shipping wrapper
var Raven = require('raven');
var shippo = require('shippo')('shippo_test_key');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//Test

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World! ' + 'hey')
})
app.post('/newship/', function (req, res) {

  var addressFrom  = {
      "object_purpose":"PURCHASE",
      "name": Mr Shippotester,
      "company":"Shippo",
      "street1":"215 Clayton St.",
      "city":"San Francisco",
      "state":"CA",
      "zip":"94117",
      "country":"US", //iso2 country code
      "phone":"+1 555 341 9393",
      "email":"support@goshippo.com",
  };

  // example address_to object dict
  var addressTo = {
      "object_purpose":"PURCHASE",
      "name": req.body.fnames + ' ' + req.body.lnames,
      "company": req.body.company,
      "street1":req.body.street,
      "city":req.body.city,
      "state":req.body.state,
      "zip":req.body.zipcode,
      "country": req.body.country, //iso2 country code
      "phone":"+1 555 341 9393",
      "email":"support@goshippo.com",
  };

  // parcel object dict
  var parcelOne = {
      "length":"5",
      "width":"5",
      "height":"5",
      "distance_unit":"in",
      "weight":"2",
      "mass_unit":"lb"
  };


  var shipment = {
      "object_purpose": "PURCHASE",
      "address_from": addressFrom,
      "address_to": addressTo,
      "parcel": [parcelOne],
      "submission_type": "DROPOFF"
  };

  shippo.transaction.create({
      "shipment": shipment,
      "servicelevel_token": "dhl_express_domestic_express_doc",
      "carrier_account": "account_id",
      "label_file_type": "png"
  })
  .then(function(transaction) {
      shippo.transaction.list({
        "rate": transaction.rate
      })
      .then(function(mpsTransactions) {
          mpsTransactions.results.forEach(function(mpsTransaction){
              if(mpsTransaction.object_status == "SUCCESS") {
                  console.log("Label URL: %s", mpsTransaction.label_url);
                  console.log("Tracking Number: %s", mpsTransaction.tracking_number);
                  console.log("E-Mail: %s", mpsTransaction.object_owner);
                  console.log(mpsTransaction.object_status);
                  res.status(200).send("Label can be found under: " + mpsTransaction.label_url));
              } else {
                  // hanlde error transactions
                  console.log("Message: %s", mpsTransactions.messages);
              }
          });
      })
  }, function(err) {
      // Deal with an error
      console.log("There was an error creating transaction : %s", err.detail);
      res.send("something happened :O")
  });
})
app.post('/successp', function (req, res) {

  var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
  // Charge the user's card:
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: "eur",
  description: "Example charge",
  source: token,
}, function(err, charge) {
  // asynchronously called
});
 res.send('Thanks!')
})
app.post('/successp', function (req, res) {

  var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
  // Charge the user's card:
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: "eur",
  description: "Example charge",
  source: token,
}, function(err, charge) {
  // asynchronously called
});
 res.send('Thanks!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

My HTML-Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>




<form action="https://ocelot-kgxujaijbj.now.sh/newship/" method="post">
  Company (Leave blank if you don't belong to one): <input type="text" name="company"><br>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fnames"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lnames"><br>
  Street and Number: <input type="text" name="street"><br>
  City: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
  State: <input type="text" name="state"><br>
  ZIP/PLZ: <input type="text" name="zipcode"><br>
  Country (Please use the iso code, for example "US" for the USA or 'DE' for Germany): <input type="text" name="country"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The server is valid, so you try it out by yourself.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using an http client such as Postman to try and send a request to the endpoint outside of your code?

Comment: Done: Cannot POST /newship/(params here) @m_callens

Comment: Could someone else help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with the code that you have submitted there. Also, even though its a test token, I strongly encourage you to edit the code there to omit it from the post.

I have made some edits to the code that you have provided, but you simply had some errors like on the `addressFrom` you were missing quotes around `Mr. Shippotester`. Also, you had an extra `)` where you had `res.status(200).send("Label can be found under: " + mpsTransaction.label_url);`

I strongly suggest reviewing your `server.js` for any errors (and I would be surprised its actually running).

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var http = require('http');
//Shippo shipping wrapper
var Raven = require('raven');
var shippo = require('shippo')('<YOUR API TEST TOKEN>');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
//Test

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
})
app.post('/newship/', function (req, res) {

  var addressFrom  = {
      "object_purpose":"PURCHASE",
      "name": "Mr Shippotester",
      "company":"Shippo",
      "street1":"215 Clayton St.",
      "city":"San Francisco",
      "state":"CA",
      "zip":"94117",
      "country":"US", //iso2 country code
      "phone":"+1 555 341 9393",
      "email":"support@goshippo.com",
  };

  // example address_to object dict
  var addressTo = {
      "object_purpose":"PURCHASE",
      "name": req.body.fnames + ' ' + req.body.lnames,
      "company": req.body.company,
      "street1":req.body.street,
      "city":req.body.city,
      "state":req.body.state,
      "zip":req.body.zipcode,
      "country": req.body.country, //iso2 country code
      "phone":"+1 555 341 9393",
      "email":"support@goshippo.com",
  };

  // parcel object dict
  var parcelOne = {
      "length":"5",
      "width":"5",
      "height":"5",
      "distance_unit":"in",
      "weight":"2",
      "mass_unit":"lb"
  };


  var shipment = {
      "object_purpose": "PURCHASE",
      "address_from": addressFrom,
      "address_to": addressTo,
      "parcel": [parcelOne],
      "submission_type": "DROPOFF"
  };

  shippo.transaction.create({
      "shipment": shipment,
      "servicelevel_token": "dhl_express_domestic_express_doc",
      "carrier_account": "9f123316d413417d9cc48627c402772c",
      "label_file_type": "png"
  })
  .then(function(transaction) {
      shippo.transaction.list({
        "rate": transaction.rate
      })
      .then(function(mpsTransactions) {
          mpsTransactions.results.forEach(function(mpsTransaction){
              if(mpsTransaction.object_status == "SUCCESS") {
                  console.log("Label URL: %s", mpsTransaction.label_url);
                  console.log("Tracking Number: %s", mpsTransaction.tracking_number);
                  console.log("E-Mail: %s", mpsTransaction.object_owner);
                  console.log(mpsTransaction.object_status);
                  res.status(200).send("Label can be found under: " + mpsTransaction.label_url);
              } else {
                  // hanlde error transactions
                  console.log("Message: %s", mpsTransactions.messages);
              }
          });
      })
  }, function(err) {
      // Deal with an error
      console.log("There was an error creating transaction : %s", err.detail);
      res.send("something happened :O")
  });
})
app.post('/successp', function (req, res) {

  var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
  // Charge the user's card:
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: "eur",
  description: "Example charge",
  source: token,
}, function(err, charge) {
  // asynchronously called
});
 res.send('Thanks!')
})
app.post('/successp', function (req, res) {

  var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
  // Charge the user's card:
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: "eur",
  description: "Example charge",
  source: token,
}, function(err, charge) {
  // asynchronously called
});
 res.send('Thanks!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>




<form action="http://localhost:3000/newship" method="post">
  Company (Leave blank if you don't belong to one): <input type="text" name="company"><br>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fnames"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lnames"><br>
  Street and Number: <input type="text" name="street"><br>
  City: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
  State: <input type="text" name="state"><br>
  ZIP/PLZ: <input type="text" name="zipcode"><br>
  Country (Please use the iso code, for example "US" for the USA or 'DE' for Germany): <input type="text" name="country"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem! Also, thanks for removing the test token from the original post.